# spring-boot security identify by token

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, spring-security, firebase-security

I got an app and I wanna create a connection to my rest-api.

Each user will get a "token" which will automatically be refreshed by google and co. In my requests, I will send the token and if it can be resolved to the user, the request should be answered, else if it is not up to date, I just wanna drop the request and return an error.

Are there still some possibilities?

Thanks for your help!

Current starting:

https://gist.github.com/PascalKu/97bca9506ad4f31c9e13f8fe8973d75b

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement custom authentication in spring. I did the same thing but I had a db like:

fb_email_address | user_id | other_fields...

You must create these classes:

```
@Component
class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) {
        String theToken = request.getParameter('theToken');
        TokenAuthentication tokenAuth = new TokenAuthentication(theToken)
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(tokenAuth)   
    }
}
```

You need to add the authentication provider to spring's security system:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebConfigHolder extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired private TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider)
    }
}
```

Implement authentication provider which actually checks to see if the token is valid.

```
@Component
class TokenAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

//called by provider manager at some point during execution of security filters, I think
//it's the security api's job to call this
//the fbauthentication we create in our fbauthenticationfilter gets passed into this
@Override
@Transactional
Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) {
    TokenAuthentication tokenAuthentication = (TokenAuthentication) auth;
    String theToken = auth.getThetoken();

    boolean theTokenIsInDB = ///CHECK TO SEE IF TOKEN IS IN DB
    if(theTokenIsInDB) {
        TokenAuthentication t = new TokenAuthentication();
        t.setAuthenticated(true);
        return t;
    } else {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Could not find user");
    }
}

@Override
boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    boolean ret = TokenAuthentication.isAssignableFrom(authentication)
    return TokenAuthentication.isAssignableFrom(authentication)
}
}
```

You need a simple Authentication Class that is just the object that's used to store the credentials while spring is waiting for the thread to get to the spring security filter; once it gets to that filter it passes authentication objects to the providers that support them. This allows you to have multiple authentication methods like FB, Google, custom tokens, etc... In my app I use FB tokens and in my provider, I check to see if the FB token corresponds to an authorized email address on my whitelist of email addresses. If it does, the user gets access to my app.

```
public class TokenAuthentication extends Authentication{
    String token;
    boolean isAuthenticated = false;
    public TokenAuthentication(String theToken) { this.token = theToken;}
    //getters and setters
}
```

What this code all does is, whenever someone accesses your API such as /api/person/get?theToken=132x8591dkkad8FjajamM9

1. The filter you created is run on every request. It checks to see if theToken was passed in and adds the TokenAuthentication to spring security.
2. At some point in the filter chain, spring security filter will run, and it will see that a TokenAuthentication has been created, and will search for a provider that can perform authentication on that. That happens to be your TokenAuthenticationProvider.
3. TokenAuthenticationProvider does the actual authentication. If it returns an authentication object that has isAuthenticated set to true, then the user will be allowed to access that api call.
4. Once authenticated, a user doesn't need to pass theToken again until his cookies are cleared or you invalidate his session. So he can call /api/person without the query parameters for the rest of his interactions. That's because the authentication is stored as a session-scoped data in spring.

Hope that helps. Let me know if anything's missing.

Comment: The following does not work for me: https://github.com/PascalKu/test-project Could you provide an eye on it please?